# Python get microseconds from time stamp into uint64

Tags: python, numpy

The purpose of this function is to get the microseconds from a numpy timestamp elapsed since the unix epoch.

Would this conversion eventually overflow because the data type is restricted to an int64 instead of a uint64?

```
dt = np.datetime64('2023-01-01T00:00:00')
timestamp_microsec = int((dt - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'us'))
```

And is there a way to do it using numpy `u8` data type that won't have that problem?

Comment: The number of microseconds since the Unix epoch is `1.678×10^15 μs`. The largest number that a signed 64 bit into can hold is `9.223 × 10^18`. So, this will work fine until the date `Jan 10, 294247`. That's about 300,000 years from now so I think you'll be fine for the time being.